# How to bundle custom suitescript 2.0 modules?

Tags: netsuite

When creating a bundle, it lets you select the suitescripts to include. However, I don't see any option to select custom suitescript modules (which are simply .js files in the file cabinet). The bundle UI gives you the option to choose files, but it appears to exclude .js files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your custom 2.0 modules and check the 'Available in SuiteBundles'.  This should allow you to add them to your bundle.

Another option is to select the folder where your files are located.  There should be a Folder selection/tree when selecting components for your bundle.

Comment: "Edit your custom 2.0 modules and check the 'Available in SuiteBundles'. This should allow you to add them to your bundle."

Ah, perfect - that's the solution, thanks!